# Why am I getting these pyflakes E syntax errors when using pypdf?

Tags: python, syntax-error, pypdf

I am using the code examples found [here](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/add-watermark.html#) and getting an error message in lines 2-4 here that says "Syntax error in forward annotation *code line* (pyflakes E)".

```
def stamp(
    content_pdf:"C:/Users/capta/spyder-py3/f'row{row}filled.pdf",
    stamp_pdf: "C:/Users/capta/Pictures/whitesq.png",
    pdf_result: "C:/Users/capta/spyder-py3/f'row{row}done.pdf",
    page_indices: Union[Literal["ALL"], List[int]] = "ALL",
):
```

Can anyone explain what is causing this error and how I can fix it?

The full code that I am using is as follows. Note this is incomplete, I am working through it:

```
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Union, Literal, List
from pypdf import Transformation
from pypdf import PdfWriter, PdfReader


def stamp(
    content_pdf:"C:/Users/capta/spyder-py3/f'row{row}filled.pdf",
    stamp_pdf: "C:/Users/capta/Pictures/whitesq.png",
    pdf_result: "C:/Users/capta/spyder-py3/f'row{row}done.pdf",
    page_indices: Union[Literal["ALL"], List[int]] = "ALL",
):
    stamp_page = PdfReader(stamp_pdf).pages[0]

    writer = PdfWriter()

    reader = PdfReader(content_pdf)
    if page_indices == "ALL":
        page_indices = list(range(0, len(reader.pages)))
    for index in page_indices:
        content_page = reader.pages[index]
        content_page.merge_transformed_page(
            stamp_page,
            Transformation.translate(5,5),
            Transformation()
        )
        writer.add_page(content_page)

    with open(pdf_result, "wb") as fp:
        writer.write(fp)
```

I've tried changing the forward slashed to backslashes (fixed a different error I had with pathways before) but then the line was flagged for incorrect syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is confusing **function default arguments** (what value an argument has if the caller of a function doesn't provide any values), and **type annotations** (what's the expected *type* of a function argument, like "str" or "list of ints").

Default arguments are specified with `=`, and type arguments with `:`. Arguments can have boths, like `page_indices` already does. So try:

```
def stamp(
    #          v the type annotation is str
    content_pdf: str = "C:/Users/capta/spyder-py3/f'row{row}filled.pdf",
    #                ^ and the default value is the path 
    stamp_pdf: str = "C:/Users/capta/Pictures/whitesq.png",
    pdf_result: str = "C:/Users/capta/spyder-py3/f'row{row}done.pdf",
    page_indices: Union[Literal["ALL"], List[int]] = "ALL",
    #           ^        this one is correct       ^
):
```

This allows you to call `stamp()` by providing any or none of the arguments, with those paths being the default values .

If instead you're trying to *call* the function with those parameters, you should keep the function definition as-is from the example, and instead call it like so:

```
# Declare the function.
def stamp(
    content_pdf: str,
    stamp_pdf: str,
    pdf_result: str,
    page_indices: Union[Literal["ALL"], List[int]] = "ALL",
):
    # Keep the function body as before, omitted here for simplicity.
    ...

# Outside the function body, and after it has been declared,
# call the function with the values you want.
stamp(
    content_pdf="C:/Users/capta/spyder-py3/f'row{row}filled.pdf",
    stamp_pdf="C:/Users/capta/Pictures/whitesq.png",
    pdf_result="C:/Users/capta/spyder-py3/f'row{row}done.pdf"
)
```